# ggplot: map linetype to factor and force solid line on one specific level?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot multiple lines with different linetypes (for a print-friendly plot where colors are not the best idea). There is one line that refers to our "main" category, so I want to keep it with a solid line for easier visualization, how can I automatically map factors to line types and force a specific line type for one specific factor level?

Here's an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(time=c(1:10,1:10),
                 X=c(cumsum(rnorm(10)),cumsum(rnorm(10))),
                 categ=c(rep("b",10),rep("a",10)))
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=time,y=X)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=categ))
```

How can I still keep the linetype mapped by the factor variable `categ`, but force, for example, the level `b` to have the solid linetype?

Comment: You can use `scale_linetype_manual` and supply a named vector to `values`

Comment: I know, but I would like a lazy solution that would allow me to type only one value. For example, if it was colors and I had like 12 colors and wanted one specific category to have a `"black"` colored line, is it possible to avoid typing the other 11 colors?

Comment: The first linetype level is always solid, as far as I know. Since you want it for your "main" category, why not set that as the first level in the factor? You can use `relevel()` for that, & avoid specifying anything for the other levels.